# How to insert a timeDatePicker control into Access db whose value has been formatted for time only

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have altered the `timeDatePicker` control with this code:

```
dateTimePickerResTime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePickerResTime.CustomFormat = "HH:mm";
dateTimePickerResTime.ShowUpDown = true;
```

And now looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to insert the value into the date/time field in access it is throwing an error

Error:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Code:

```
connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Booking] ([TableID], BookingName, BookingNumber, BookingDate, BookingTime PartySize) VALUES (@TableID, @BookingName, @BookingPhoneNumber, @BookingDate, @BookingTime, @PartySize)";
            command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[] {
                    new OleDbParameter("@TableID", textBoxResTableID.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingName", textBoxResName.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingPhoneNumber", textBoxResNum.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingDate", dateTimePickerBooking.Value),
                     new OleDbParameter("@BookingTime", dateTimePickerResTime.Value), // time
                    new OleDbParameter("@PartySize", textBoxResPartySize.Text)
                });

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
```

Comment: You didn't _even_ show your insert code and error message. By the way, be sure you insert this as a `TimeSpan` or `DateTime`, not it's string representation.

Comment: You need to put comma to separate `BookingTime PartySize` columns. Voted to close as typo.

Comment: comma doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: comma doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the *OleDbType*, like (pseudo):

```
new OleDbParameter("@BookingTime", OleDbType.Date, dateTimePickerResTime.Value),
```

However, you can't have that mix of variables, so you'll have to create the parameter objects one by one with *name* and *data type*, then assign the *value*.